# Google Spreadsheet Script - Replace solved formulas in column with their answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have column A filled with formulas that output "" when unsolved. I'm trying to write a script that checks column A for non-blank cells, and when it finds them it replaces the formula with the plain-text answer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copyTo` has the `contentsOnly` option

```
function testReplaceFormula() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var row=1; row<=s.getLastRow(); row++) {
    var r = s.getRange(row, 1);
    if (r.getValue() != "") {
      r.copyTo(r, {contentsOnly: true});
    }
  }
}
```